# Error in importing orders in the Shiprocket account from Shopify channel

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I couldn't import orders in the Shiprocket account from your Shopify channel due to the following reason:

Error Received :- "Server error: `GET https://fc14b70f3ba850c4411e17ab2a8833d4:***@....myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/orders/count.json` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: {quot;errorsquot;:quot;Internal Server Errorquot;} "

Due to this, I won't be able to view new Shopify orders in your Shiprocket account. Can u help me?

[image]